# coordinate ring of quasi projective varieties are regular?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth quasi-projective variety over a field $k$ (you may assume $k$ is alg. closed if necessary). Then, is it true that the coordinate ring of $X$, namely $H^0(X,O_X)$ (the global sections of structure sheaf of $X$), is always a regular ring?

Here by a regular ring R I mean that the the local rings of R at prime ideals are all regular local rings. Of course, if X is smooth affine variety then it is true, and if X is projective variety then $H^0(X,O_X)=k$, so the above holds obviously. My question is whether the same thing holds for open subvarieties of smooth projective varieties.

Comment: Interesting question! Usually these "do things affine locally hold imply global sections hold" are deceivingly tricky (e.g. finitely type over $k$). My only observation at this point, which may not be helpful, is to use the sheaf condition to understand $\mathcal{O}_X(X)$ as a subring of the finite product of regular rings, which are certainly regular. I don't think there are any nice conditions that say "a subring of the form ___ of a regular ring is regular" so this might not be helpful, but perhaps you can do something with it.